# Partial re-initialization of C++ object through constructor

Tags: c++

I am looking for an optimal pattern for partial re-initialization of a C++ object.

With partial re-initialization I mean that some members (`step_param` in the code example) need to keep its values and other members (`value` in the code example) are re-init'ed.

**Important point:** The bloat and redundancy of an init() or reset() member function that does basically the same as the constructor should be avoided.

So far I have the following solution:

```
namespace reinit_example
{
    struct reinit_t {} reinit;

    struct stepper_t
    {
        int step_param; // keep parameter
        int value;

        stepper_t()
            : step_param(1)
            , value(step_param)
        {}
        stepper_t( const stepper_t & c, reinit_t )
            :   step_param(c.step_param)
            ,   value(step_param)
        {}

        void step()
        {
            value += step_param;
        }

    };

    void use_cases_1()
    {
        stepper_t c;
        // use c
        c.step();
        // and later reinit
        c = stepper_t(c,reinit);
    }
} // namespace
```

It should also work well with inheritance and composition:

```
namespace reinit_example
{
    struct stepper_2_t : public stepper_t
    {
        int step_param_2; // keep parameter
        int value_2;

    public:
        stepper_2_t()
            : step_param_2(0)
            , value_2(step_param_2)
        {}

        stepper_2_t( const stepper_2_t & cc, reinit_t )
            :   stepper_t(cc)
            ,   step_param_2(cc.step_param_2)
            ,   value_2(step_param+2)
        {}
        void step()
        {
            stepper_t::step();
            value_2 += value + step_param_2;
        }
    };

    struct stepper_comp_t
    {
        stepper_t c;
        stepper_2_t cc;
    public:
        stepper_comp_t()
        {}
        stepper_comp_t( const stepper_comp_t & d, reinit_t )
            :   c(d.c,reinit)
            ,   cc(d.cc,reinit)
        {}
        void step()
        {
            c.step();
            cc.step();
        }
    };

    void use_cases_2()
    {
        stepper_2_t cc;
        // use cc, change config
        cc.step();
        // maybe change config
        cc.step_param = 2;
        // reinit
        cc = stepper_2_t(cc,reinit);

        stepper_comp_t d;
        d = stepper_comp_t(d,reinit);
    }
} // namespace
```

C++11 non-static member initialization makes it even simpler:

```
#if __has_feature(cxx_nonstatic_member_init)
namespace reinit_example
{
    struct stepper_11_t
    {
        int step_param = 0 ; // keep value
        int value = step_param;

        stepper_11_t()
        {}

        stepper_11_t( const stepper_11_t & c11, reinit_t )
            :   step_param(c11.step_param)
        {}
    };

    void use_cases_3()
    {
        stepper_11_t c11;
        c11 = stepper_11_t(c11,reinit);
    }

} // namespace
#endif
```

For testing:

```
int main()
{
    reinit_example::use_cases_1();
    reinit_example::use_cases_2();
#if  __has_feature(cxx_nonstatic_member_init)
    reinit_example::use_cases_3();
#endif
}
```

Solution proposed by Jerry Coffin: Parameters are moved into a separate struct, which is  passed to the constructor to reinit.

```
namespace reinit_example
{

    struct stepper_config_t
    {
        struct config_t
        {
            config_t()
                :   step_param(1)
            {}
            int step_param;
            int other_param;
        };
        config_t config;
        int value;

        stepper_config_t()
            : value(config.step_param)
        {}

        stepper_config_t( const config_t & c)
            :   config(c)
            ,   value(c.step_param)
        {}

        void step()
        {
            value += config.step_param;
        }

    };

    void use_cases_4()
    {
        stepper_config_t c;
        // use c
        // and later reinit
        c = stepper_config_t(c.config);
    }
} // namespace
```

Comment: [What problem are you actually trying to solve?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) This sounds like a lot of work to do something that doesn't really make a lot of sense anyway ("partial reinitialization"?) since C++ objects are initialized (constructed) only once in their lifetimes.

Comment: you answered extremely fast. did you really think about it?

Comment: It was not an answer, it was a comment asking for clarification. And yes, I did really think about it, and came to the conclusion that this might not be the right way to solve whatever problem that you're trying to solve. That's why I'm asking what your actual problem is. [You're trying to do X, and you thought of solution Y. So you're asking about solution Y, without even mentioning X. The problem is, there might be a better solution, but we can't know that unless you describe what X is.](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341)

Comment: You could use the placement new operator with the original address, i.e. `new ((void*)&c) CC` but this is disgusting (and probably undefined behavior)

Comment: "In C++11 delegating constructors can be used:" -- I may be overlooking something, but I'm not seeing any delegating constructors in that example.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Assuming the previous object was correctly destructed in-place (with `c->~CC()`) it is legal and not UB, I believe.

Comment: @hvd: ... and beyond this, this isn't actually true either: when calling a constructor, constructors for the base are always executed. When not mentioning them in the initializer list, they are default constructed (which may have no effect, though).

Comment: @hpc Okay, but in that case, I don't see why you'd want a NSDMI: you only want the `step_param = 0` with the default constructor. If you do want to set it to 0 it in multiple constructors, I suppose you _could_ create an `init` method and call it from every constructor except the reinit.

Comment: My immediate reaction is that you've probably conflated what should be two separate classes/objects into one. With them separated, initializing one independently of the other becomes trivial.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: True, that is a good/better solution. Especially in the case when there are many configuration parameters that can be bundled into one struct.

Answer (score 0):

i believe you should be looking for completely different design pattern.

for example, the "keeper" members should form a full-featured class, while the rest of the members that you don't want to keep would be considered a context of this class (would be another class, used to do some operations on the first class).

this is kind of similar to the [flyweight design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. _the "keeper" members should form a full-featured class_: this corresponds to the proposed solution of Jerry Coffin. I wrote it up in in the stepper_config_t class. To use a context class would mean to have an additional class per class and more indirections (the config class needs to be accessed from the context class). the advantage of the solution with the reinit-constructor is that no helper classes are required.

Comment: Well, yes and no. The "reinit constructor" will probably reduce the amount of code you need to write, but i believe it would complicate the code in the long run (maintenance, extensibility, etc). I believe the "two class" solution is cleaner, although it's more work.

Comment: But as i said, this should be used in case the "keeper" members form a full-featured class. In your example, the "keeper" is only an integer, there's no sense in making class out of an integer, since there are no (reasonable) operations to do on it (except get/set). For that, i'd recommend the inplace constructor Basile Starynkevitvc proposed, as it involves no copying.

Comment: if `c->~CC(); new ((void*)&c);` is not UB (as believed) then it's just equal to `c = C();`. I prefer the later. The overhead should be  optimized away. But this does full construction. For partial re-init c=C(c,reinit) does the job and for simple classes its an lightweight solution.